# Why is ViewPager2 delaying to load pages?

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I decided to give a try on the new and now available stable release of `ViewPager2`.

My `ViewPager2` have a lot of pages, and  I am using `TabLayout` to give each page (fragment) scrollable tab titles, but I am facing a delay when loading the `ViewPager2` for the first time in my view.

Is this the normal behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out what was causing the `ViewPager2` initial delay to load the pages.

It happens I was using `TabLayout` from `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` along with the `ViewPager2` to give scrollable tab titles to each page. But if you have a lot of pages which is my case, the UI takes time to setup each tab and place in the UI.

The solution is to remove the `TabLayout` from `ViewPager2`, and if you need to display a title, use the `ToolBar` as title page indicator for each page by changing and setting `ToolBar` text according to your needs.

Looking the bright side you end up with more clean UI, by having more space in screen for your  `ViewPager2` to display its content to the user.

Another thing I noticed is if you want to take full advantage of `ViewPager2` performance benefits, then use the default viewpager's offscreenPageLimit, as stated bellow:

> public void setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)
>
> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the currently visible page(s). Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed. Set this to OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT_DEFAULT to use RecyclerView's caching strategy. The given value must either be larger than 0, or #OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT_DEFAULT.
>
> Pages within limit pages away from the current page are created and added to the view hierarchy, even though they are not visible on the screen. Pages outside this limit will be removed from the view hierarchy, but the ViewHolders will be recycled as usual by RecyclerView.
>
> This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once, less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as the user pages back and forth.
>
> You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex layouts. By default it is set to OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT_DEFAULT.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

That being said I strongly recommend the replacement of your `ViewPager` to `ViewPager2` for all cases, because  `ViewPager` is no longer receiving Google support, and `ViewPager2` has a lot to offer other than what I spoke here:

> RTL (right-to-left) layout support
>
> Vertical orientation support
>
> Reliable Fragment support (including handling changes to the underlying Fragment collection)
>
> Dataset change animations (including DiffUtil support)

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2

Comment: In my case I needed to set offscreenPageLimit to at least 1. Default is -1 and loads items just as they need to appear (recycler based), which was too late for me. Overriding default behavior caused pages to load in advance, which fixed my issue.

Comment: I am nither using recyclerview nor tablayout , just clicking button it should load next screen and its taking 1-2 second to load next screen.

Comment: @GyanSwaroopAwasthi a lot of UI components on screen makes the UI slow, besides if you are doing some database or file reading or other heavy work to fetch content before displaying it, you will have to do it asynchronous and use a progress bar indicating that content is not ready to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [whole set of improvements](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0) over ViewPager:

> - RTL (right-to-left) layout support
> - Vertical orientation support
> - Reliable Fragment support (including handling changes to the underlying Fragment collection)
> - Dataset change animations (including DiffUtil support)

These features will never be fixed in ViewPager, so migrating to ViewPager2 would be the only way to get these features.

Comment: I loading 20 fragments with ViewPager2 (new version) took 7 seconds (slow). When using the ViewPager (old version) it only takes 3 seconds (fast). I finally reverted to the old version (ViewPager) for fast application performance.

Comment: @Ihdina - given that ViewPager2 does no blocking work whatsoever, you should probably profile your app to see what of *your code* is doing something wrong, rather than blame ViewPager2.

Comment: When I load 20 fragments in ViewPager2, I set the setOffscreenPageLimit(20). Everything runs normally, it's just that the viewpager2 loading process is slow (7-8 seconds).

When I don't set the setOffscreenPageLimit, the viewpage2 loading process becomes very fast (2-3 second), but I lose the data in the fragment, when I move from one tab to anothers.

Comment: ViewPager2 is faster when moving from one fragment to other fragment than ViewPager, but the main problem when loading the first time, ViewPager2 is twice longer than ViewPager.

Comment: Again, ViewPager2 does no blocking work whatsoever, so you should profile your app to see what excessive work your code is doing.

Comment: main problem with ViewPager2 is scrolling from 1 fragment to the next. the animation is soooooooooo slow. you cannot control its speed. So the menuitems that should be displayed in fragment2 only gets shown once the animation ends. which is ugly.