# Problem when migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2

This viewpager is already running perfectly.

I want to migrate from **viewpager** to **viewpager2**. But there is a problem when I scroll viewpager2 left/right, the tables in the fragment sometimes appear sometime not. Is there something wrong with my code?

**ViewPager(old) - this is running perfectly**

```
private static class SettingAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SettingAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment, @NonNull String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        titleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

*SettingAdapter* call from *onCreateView* in *Fragment* (old)

```
titles = getSettingTabTitlesRes(context);
adapter = new SettingAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);

if (titles.length == 15) {
    adapter.addFragment(new NetworkFragment(), titles[0]);
    adapter.addFragment(new PopulationsFragment(), titles[1]);
    adapter.addFragment(new BankFragment(), titles[2]);
    adapter.addFragment(new PetrolStationFragment(), titles[3]);
    adapter.addFragment(new DispenserFragment(), titles[4]);
    adapter.addFragment(new ProductFragment(), titles[5]);
    adapter.addFragment(new EmployeeFragment(), titles[6]);
    adapter.addFragment(new NozzleFragment(), titles[7]);
    adapter.addFragment(new PaymentMethodFragment(), titles[8]);
    adapter.addFragment(new WorkScheduleFragment(), titles[9]);
    adapter.addFragment(new ReceiptPaperFragment(), titles[10]);
    adapter.addFragment(new CustomersFragment(), titles[11]);
    adapter.addFragment(new UserAccountFragment(), titles[12]);
    adapter.addFragment(new LicenseFragment(), titles[13]);
    adapter.addFragment(new HelpFragment(), titles[14]);
}

binding.settingViewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
binding.settingTablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

**ViewPager2(new) - PROBLEM IN HERE..**

```
private static class SettingAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public SettingAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        Log.i("xxx", "createFragment: " + position);
        switch (position) {
            default:
            case 0:
                return new NetworkFragment();
            case 1:
                return new PopulationsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new BankFragment();
            case 3:
                return new PetrolStationFragment();
            case 4:
                return new DispenserFragment();
            case 5:
                return new ProductFragment();
            case 6:
                return new EmployeeFragment();
            case 7:
                return new NozzleFragment();
            case 8:
                return new PaymentMethodFragment();
            case 9:
                return new WorkScheduleFragment();
            case 10:
                return new ReceiptPaperFragment();
            case 11:
                return new CustomersFragment();
            case 12:
                return new UserAccountFragment();
            case 13:
                return new LicenseFragment();
            case 14:
                return new HelpFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 15;
    }
}
```

*SettingAdapter* call from *onCreateView* in *Fragment* (new)

```
String[] titles = getSettingTabTitlesRes(context);
settingAdapter = new SettingAdapter(this);

binding.settingViewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
binding.settingViewpager.setAdapter(settingAdapter);

new TabLayoutMediator(binding.settingTablayout, binding.settingViewpager, (tab, position) -> {
    tab.setText(titles[position]);
}).attach();
```

Screenshots when use Viewpager2

[Table is invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOg0P.jpg)
[Table is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCpGx.jpg)

Comment: post screenshots also

Comment: I've added a screen shot, thanks

Comment: I posted an answer see the link and follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2bookmark_border**

`ViewPager2` is an improved version of the `ViewPager` library that offers enhanced functionality and addresses common difficulties with using `ViewPager`. If your app already uses `ViewPager`.

[Follow this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration)

Comment: I've followed that instructions it's exactly the same, but the table is sometimes not visible, sometimes is visible. Is there any other way?

Comment: I resolved my problem with replace setOffscreenPageLimit(2) to setOffscreenPageLimit(15).

Comment: you have 15 fragments? oh yes great job

Comment: I'm using the same user interface and data, but why does viewpager2 take 8 seconds before displaying when I clicked menu settings, while viewpager only takes 3 seconds?

Comment: this link will hep you ot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951551/why-is-viewpager2-delaying-to-load-pages